# GStreamer full HD video RTP stream on Raspberry Pi

Tags: streaming-video, gstreamer

I am trying to build a video pipeline with GStreamer.

In the end it should be a full duplex Full HD video conferencing solution. As the Raspberry Pi 3 is not capable to encode and decode the video stream at the same time I am using a Logitech C920 to encode the video. So the my RPi only needs to encode and decode Audio, and decode the H.264 video.

I build GStreamer from source (1.13.0.1 & 1.12.0) as the 1.4.4 from the raspbian repository had problems with G.722 encoding. Libraries like `gst-omx` (RaspiVideo), `libsrtp` (encryption), libwebrtc (echocanceling) (0.1 in repo to old - so manually downloaded 0.3) are build as well. So i do have `omxh264dec` - but I couldn't find a video sink to play the 1080p video smoothly. So I tried to pipe (with a named pipe) the h.264 stream do hello_video or the `omxplayer`, which worked fine as long as I stay local. As soon as I try to stream it over RTP hello_video doesn't show anything.

Working pipe:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc
location=/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264 ! filesink
location=/home/pi/test & /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/hello_video.bin
/home/pi/test even with stream from camera: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! 'video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! filesink
location=/home/pi/test & /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/hello_video.bin 
/home/pi/test
```

Not working when transmitting over RTP:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! 'video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.0.0.129 port=5000 \ & gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! 'video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! filesink location=/home/pi/test \ & /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/hello_video.bin /home/pi/test
```

Not working without UDP RTP:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! queue ! rtph264depay ! filesink location=/home/pi/test \ & /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/hello_video.bin /home/pi/test
```

So it seems that something happens as soon as the video stream gets enclosed in RTP.

I know that the RTP Stream works, as I can receive it on my VM and play it without any trouble. But, of course, on the VM I can use the autovideosink. working receive on Ubuntu:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! \ application/x-rtp,\ encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! \ rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! \ autovideosink
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The glimagesink seems to have a problem with Raspbian running xserver. Using Raspbian Light with glimagesink works like a charm. So no need for the "hello_video" workaround.

So the final pipeline is:
Sender: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! 'video/x-v264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.0.0.129 port=5000
Recipient: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! glimagesink

Thank You